# How to check if an indirectly referenced variable is unset

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
function setProperty () {
local name="${1}"
local Id=${2}
local _thisVarNam=_${name}_${3}

for (( ctX=0 ; ctX<${2} ; ctX++ )) ; do
if [[ -z ${!_thisVarNam[${ctX}]+x} ]] ;then
 echo "${ctX} is unset"
 eval "$_thisVarNam[${ctX}]=" #so set it
else
 echo "set"
fi
done
echo
}

for (( ctY=0 ; ctY<4 ; ctY++ )) ; do
 setProperty "First" ${ctY} "Second"
done
```

This code outputs

```
0 is unset

set
1 is unset

set
1 is unset
2 is unset
```

So it's only checking if ${_First_Second[0]} is unset each time, not ${_First_Second[${ctX}]}.
If I alter the conditional to direct reference

```
if [[ -z ${_First_Second[${ctX}]+x} ]] ;then
```

it outputs

```
0 is unset

set
1 is unset

set
set
2 is unset
```

which is what I'm expecting. What am I doing wrong with

```
if [[ -z ${!_thisVarNam[${ctX}]+x} ]] ;then
```

Using bash version 3.2.57(1)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't think you showed all your variables (there's no reference to where `_First_Second` is set), but I think this:

```
${!_thisVarNam[${ctX}]+x}
```

reads the value of `_thisVarNam[${ctX}]` and uses that as a variable name. Which is not the same as taking the value of `_thisVarNam`, using that as an array name, and then indexing *that* array.

Let's see:

```
$ P=(somevar othervar); 
$ somevar=foo; unset othervar

$ i=0; echo "${!P[i]-unset}"        # reads somevar
foo
$ i=1; echo "${!P[i]-unset}"        # reads othervar (not set)
unset

$ q="P[0]"; echo "${!q}"            # reads P[0]
somevar
$ q="P[1]"; echo "${!q}"            # reads P[1]
othervar

$ arrayname=P; i=1
$ q="$arrayname[$i]"     # this is just a string so same as above
$ echo "${!q}"           # still P[1]  
othervar
```

So, if `_thisVarNam` contains the name of an array, and you want to check if a member of that array is unset, you need to do something like this:

```
p="$_thisVarNam[${ctX}]"
if [ -z "${!p+x}" ] ; then ...
```

As an aside, in Bash, you can use `declare` to set a variable indirectly, no need for the full force of `eval`:

```
$ arrayname=P; i=19
$ declare "$arrayname[$i]"=qwerty
$ echo "${P[19]}"
qwerty
```

Comment: I see what you mean - I have it working ok, (I think!) but I can't quite see what I was doing wrong

If I change the code to:-
`for (( ctX=0 ; ctX<${2} ; ctX++ )) ; do
 eval "p=\${${_thisVarNam}[${ctX}]}"
 if [[ -z ${p} ]] ;then
...`
this doesn't work unless I change
`eval "$_thisVarNam[${ctX}]=" #so set it`
to
`eval "$_thisVarNam[${ctX}]=0" #so set it`
whereas that line
`eval "$_thisVarNam[${ctX}]=" #so set it`
does work if I reference directly:-
`if [[ -z ${_First_Second[${ctX}]+x} ]] ;then`

Comment: BTW _First_Second is set with

`local name="${1}"
local _thisVarNam=_${name}_${3}`

Sorry could have made that a bit simpler.

Comment: @user1321964, yeah, you can't use `[[ -z "$x" ]]` to tell the difference between an empty and an unset variable. I fixed the example in the answer, and added what I think should work.